# error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before '*' token

Tags: c, debugging

```
typedef struct states{
    char stateName[20];
    char capital[20];
    char fact* = (char*)calloc(1000,sizeof(char));
}states;
```

I do not understand why it's giving me this error in the line

```
char fact* = (char*)calloc(1000,sizeof(char));
```

It looks character per character to example code I am looking at. Can anyone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know what book/tutorial you are reading. My guess is you are misunderstanding it. It's invalid to have initializers inside a struct definition.

Comment: It's legal in C++, but in C++ you probably wouldn't bother using a `typedef`. Also, `char fact*` should be `char *fact`. Can you update your question to indicate where you got the example from ?

Comment: If dynamic memory allocation was allowed while defining structure, (_think_) what would happen when `calloc` fails and returns a null pointer?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by [kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003365/kaylum), the structure definition declares a type and not a variable that can be initialized. Your example is:

```
typedef struct states{
    char stateName[20];
    char capital[20];
    char fact* = (char*)calloc(1000,sizeof(char)); //WRONG! - Initialization inside struct!
}states;
```

In this case you're defining a type, not a variable. You will define variables of type `states` afterwards and then you'll initialize them.

Edit: you can also use initializers (assuming you're using C99 or something newer than that): [Initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)